# Image alignment using after doing a document Conversion

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

```
private static void DownloadAndConvertToPDF(FileInfo originalFileInfo, string fileLocal, string filePdfName) 
{
    try 
    {
        try
        {
            if (originalFileInfo.Extension.Equals(".pdf"))
            {
                File.Copy(fileLocal, filePdfName, true);
            }
            else
            {
                var documentConverter = new LibreOfficeLibrary.DocumentConverter();
                documentConverter.ConvertToPdf(fileLocal, filePdfName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nowadays, I use this code to do my document conversion (Office to PDF), most of the times the PDF file looks the same as the original, but sometimes the images start to lose the alignment, go beyond the footer, go too much to the right and things like that. I would like to know if there are anything I can do to make it right, I already looked at iTextSharp but I don't know all the functions about it.

Note: Filelocal = Office Document.
FilePdfName = The converted one.

Tried to use iTextSharp

Comment: How flexible are you about the _source_ format of that conversion?

Comment: The duplicate `try` without a `catch` or `finally` is a copy&paste error, I guess?

Comment: Yes, it is haha. It's my first time asking here. The format of the files that can be converted are: pptx, ppt, doc, docx, xls, xlsx.

Comment: Ok, so it's basically MS Office => PDF. LibreOffice  - in my experience - is often not 100% compatible to Microsoft Office. So, that _might_ be a problem that _might_ be solved by using a better suited library.